# Validating whether an emp is a manager in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to build a trigger that would not allow users to give a salary higher than 10,000 to employees but if the employee is a manager, I don't want the user to be able to give less than 15000 of a salary.

What I reached so far is the following

```
create or replace trigger sal_check 
before update or insert on emp
for each row
begin 
if :new.sal > 10000
then
update emp set sal = 10000;
end if;
end;
```

Now can I please take a hint of how to do a check whether the employee is a manager or not?

Note : I am using Oracle, and this is running on Scott schema, the one that actually comes with Oracle by default.

Comment: provide us some info about tables, for instance how do you know who is a manager or not?

Comment: The emp table has a column that says mgr, which contains the employee id of the mgr, since the mgr is an employee too.
Of course the emp table contains a column named empno which is the emp id 
The closest I got to figuring out who are the managers is by using the following select statement :
select mgr from emp group by mgr

Comment: and if the employee is the manager itself, it also have a value in mgr column?

Comment: yep, unless it has no mgr, like a CEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a table (not temporary) with all the managers.

Afterwords, it would be quite easy to detect if a employee is a manager or not and by making a simple select on that table you could see what should be the salary.

To determine what employees should be on the table, it would be the ones in the `mgr column`.

Answer (score 2):

If `emp` table has `mgr` column and you set up foreign key constraint, it's enough just to check whether `mgr` field is not null. Also, `update emp set sal = 10000;` in your code will cause `ORA-04091` (table is mutating), you need to change it to `:new.sal := 1000`. So you trigger will look like

```
...
 if :new.mgr IS NULL THEN
   if :new.sal > 10000
    then
   :new.sal := 10000;
   end if;
 ELSE
 if :new.sal < 15000
    then
   :new.sal := 15000;
   end if;
 END IF;
```

Comment: According to Adel's comments to the question, the only employee who would have a NULL `mgr` is the CEO.